# Looking for a simple calendar/events plugin

Tags: events, calendar

am looking for a simple calendar/events plugin with a list view by months and a pagination between months. Events would be simply made of a tile, description and the date of the event.

Here's a quick sketch:

[image]

I've tested already plugins like:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/event-calendar/
- doesnt suits my needs and gives me errors in the admin (brand new wp 3.3.1)

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/event-calendar-scheduler/
- too complex, and not events list

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/events-calendar/
- Just a widget

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/kino-event-calendar-plugin/ 
- Just a widget

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/my-calendar/
- list view but not by month and gives me an error when i open the page with events on first load after adding an event: `Warning: usort() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in C:...\plugins\my-calendar\my-calendar-output.php on line 850`

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-events-calendar/
- list view but not by month and no pagination

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/the-events-calendar/
- list view not by month and although great, pretty complex for waht i need

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-event-calendar/
- Doesnt save any event in the admin...

Am runnin glow on ideas so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I have the exact same issue. Even your image is exactly what I need. Have you come up with a suitable solution? The calender by tri.be has the functionality but it feels heavy, it's hard for me to figure out which functions to use to actually get the wanted output (as in your image), am I missing something?

Comment: If i remember well, i've been with the tri.be calendar that i customized to suit my needs.

Answer (score 3):

First off, I just want to say AMEN to this question. There are not a lot of good, reliable calendar plugins out there. I've struggled with this myself.

Judging by your list of event calendars you've tried, you've just about exhausted the list of decent to reputable plugins. I honestly think what you're looking for in a plugin, you're not going to be able to find UNLESS you do something custom (either 100% custom or customizing an existing plugin).

Personally, The Events Calendar by Modern Tribe is a superb calendar. Not only is it a great calendar plugin, it's relatively simple to modify/customize and the documentation for the plugin is WAY better than just about every other plugin on your list.

They also have support forums that are regularly maintained and used by the MT team.

http://tri.be/wordpress-events-calendar/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah that's what i thought, that it would had to be 100% custom. I already used the plugin by tri.be for another project and it's great. Will see what i can do. Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 2):

This one might do the trick for you... http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/really-simple-events/ - low functionality but easy to install and make simple events. It seems only site admins can add events though.